# GNU make implicit clean rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know there are a lot of implicit rules in make, but is there one for cleaning generated files ?

I tried searching in GNU make manual, googling, and here too, but did not find any.
My googling always takes to me to generic implicit rule hits (usually the clean keyword drops out in many hits), possibly due to my search keywords (see title of this question)

However, since it is a trivial rule, i believe there is a high chance it could be implemented, but i just can't reach it

Thank you for your time

Comment: Generated files? You mean generated by Make? Make does not know which files it generated. (And I think the answer to your question is "no".)

Comment: As noted by @Beta, it is not make that generates files, it is the shell when it executes the recipe of a rule. Make does not know what files were generated. An implicit cleaning rule should thus always delete the same types of files (`*.o`, `*.a`...) A disaster if you code in language A or O. If make had an implicit rule to delete things it would have disappeared long time ago... No, cleaning is not and shall not be implicit.

Comment: @Beta there is however, one exception to this: [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules) which appear in the chain of execution of implicit rules. The docs are a bit quirky and hard to understand, but iff the file is not explicitly named in the make file and it is e.g. a C file that comes out of a Yacc run, then make will delete it after the target rule is satisfied. But this is quite different from what you are searching, and I agree with Beta and Renaud that there shouldn't be an invisible grim reaper in your build tool.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes make does indeed remove intermediate build files in case of using its build implicit rule.. let me give you an example:
`all: libfoo.a(foo.o)`
This rule will first compile foo.c to foo.o, then archive it to generate libfoo.a, _then it will delete foo.o_
However i am closing this question as it makes sense in all your comments guys.. make does NOT know anything about files it generated... The only exception is intermediates generated by implicit rules...
Thanks all for sharing